# Unable to get the "else" part. Any input I put will give me "Guest is on list" even if they're not

Tags: python

```
#guest list
print("Guest List")
f = open("guestlist.txt","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
name=f
while(1):
    input('Input a guest name: ')
    if name==f:
        print("Guest is on list")
    else:
        print("Name is not on the list")
```

Comment: `f` is file handler, not text from file. Besides you don't assign `input()` to variable so you always compare the same `name` with `f` but you made `name=f` so they are always equal.

Comment: Still a little confused on what I should change. I called the f to text_file. Still stuck on the input() and rest.

Answer (score 0):

First read all lines of text, later get name from user and then check if name is on list.

Still problem can be uppercase/lowercase.

```
#read lines from file
f = open("guestlist.txt","r")
guest_list = f.read().split('\n') 
f.close()

print(guest_list)

while True:
    # get name from user
    name = input('Input a guest name: ')
    # check nam on list
    if name in guest_list:
        print("Guest is on list")
    else:
        print("Name is not on the list")
```